# Alert ID of current element

Tags: jquery

I'm using following code to alert id of current element.

```
<input type="text" id="desc" name="txtTitle" onclick="fun()">
```

jquery:

```
function fun () {
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(currentId);
}
```

Why does it alert "undefined"?
I have tried with:

```
var currentId =$('element').attr('id'); 
// and 
alert($(this).id); 
// and 
alert(this.id);
```

but it alerts `undefined`

Comment: If you used jQuery to add the onclick handler, you would not be asking this. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing it to:

```
<input type="text" id="desc" name="txtTitle" onclick="fun.call(this)">
```

Better, bind your event handler with jQuery, since you're using it anyway:

```
$(function() { $('#desc').click(fun); });
```

The reason your code doesn't work is that you're calling `fun()` from inside the event handler function constructed by the browser for your "onclick" attribute.  By just calling the function like that, you provide no "receiver" object — nothing for `this` to be, that is.  If you call it with `.call()` however you can explicitly do that.

Answer (score 9):

`$(this)` only works inside jQuery functions; it references nothing inside `fun()`. Instead, try this:

```
$('input#desc').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

With this HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="desc" name="txtTitle">
```

It's not particularly good practice to have `onClick=""` attributes in your HTML, hence the `$.click()` function given above. You should always put your JavaScript in a separate file (especially when using jQuery).

Answer (score 2):

just use

```
alert($(this).attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a string to the `onclick` event, the code in that string will be the function that is executed. If it calls another function, `this` will not be defined.

Either do

```
$("#desc").click(fun)
```

on document ready, or if you must work with inline events, <strike>pass `this` as an argument</strike> use the method shown by Pointy.

Answer (score 1):

Change the element to say:

```
onclick="fun(this)"
```

And the function to:

```
function fun(elem)
{
    var currentId = $(elem).attr("id");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `alert(event.target.id);` inside the function which is called by your element without passing any argument to the function.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you called `this` in global scope.

Without jQuery, you can do like below:

```
<input type="text" id="desc" name="txtTitle" onclick="fun(this)">

function fun(el) {
    alert(el.id);
}
```

With jQuery, you can do like below:

```
<input type="text" id="desc" name="txtTitle">

$(function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').click(function(){
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
```