# Need to get text of parent's div when child's div is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here when I am clicking on More Info. I want an alert showing the value present inside h3 tags. How can I do that ??

Here is the html i am working on

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6"> 
  <div class="small-box bg-red">
    <div class="inner">
      <h3>Text 1</h3>
      <p>fhjh</p>
    </div>

  <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give it an id and jquery it, via the new id

Comment: similer questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053983/alert-id-of-current-element , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239598/how-can-i-get-the-id-of-an-element-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try code below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.small-box-footer').on('click', function(e){
         e.preventDefault();        
         alert($(this).parents('.small-box').find('h3').text());
    })
})
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vsok/2upg25d1/)

Answer (score 1):

so what you want is to click on the small-box-footer link and alert the 'Text 1'?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.small-box-footer').on('click', function(evt){
         //if you don't want the default event
         evt.preventDefault();
         //show the alert text
         alert($('.inner h3').text());
    })
})
```

Comment: suppose i have a h3 tag with an id ..  then how can i refer that

Comment: @Prakhar just replace the $('.inner h3') to $('#yourH3Id')

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
$('.small-box-footer').click(function(e){
    var text = $(this).prev().children().first().text();
    console.log(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to have an event listener for the `onclick` event when someone clicks on the "more info".

you'll then need to get the closest query the dom (you can traverse upwards or alternatively go from the DOM straight to a specific element... it's cheaper to go up).

example...

Using Jquery

```
$('.small-box-footer').click(function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  // find the h3
  var text = $('.inner h3').text();
  alert(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple as just grabbing the h3 directly, skip traversing:

```js
window.showTitle = function() {
  alert($('h3').text())
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6">
  <div class="small-box bg-red">
    <div class="inner">
      <h3>Text 1</h3 
<p>fhjh</p>
</div>
<a href="#" class="small-box-footer" onclick="showTitle()">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```